# Converting CultureInfo currency between Saudi Arabia & US

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo

I have something like:

price_2.Text = CDbl(price_2.Text).ToString("C", current_culture)

**Issue/Workflow:**

And lets assume the beginning price is in dollars so lets say price_2.Text is $5.99. And when pressing a button the current_culture will change to ar-SA. So it will convert ($5.99) to (5.99 ريال‎), now that it is (5.99 ريال‎) and I change the current_culture to be en-US, this will crash, since the CDbl cannot convert that symbol after 5.99 ريال‎ to a double.

Any ideas how we can convert from CultureInfo's for currency?

Comment: `Double.Parse()`  (or TryParse) would seem to be more appropriate than that legacy `CDbl`.  Also, if it *is* currency, `Decimal` would seem to be a better choice

Comment: Changing culture invariably also requires re-creating the UI.  So it is not a problem, you'll retrieve the value from your data model, not the view.

Comment: @HansPassant not quite following that, so how do we retrieve the value from "data model", what does data model refer to.

Comment: @Plutonix so this would work for strings being converted to a double, with this characters in it? Trying it now.

Comment: Im thinking instead of doing CDbl(price_2.Text) since I am not doing any real time conversions, I could make the numbers hardcoded, and do price_2.Text = CDbl("5.99").ToString("C", current_culture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Decimal.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that lets you to specify a [NumberStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) from which to derive the currency format.

This allows the parsing method to understand how to interpret the input provided.

```
Dim numberStyle As NumberStyles = NumberStyles.Currency Or
                                  NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol Or
                                  NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or
                                  NumberStyles.AllowThousands

Dim CurrencyValue As Decimal
Dim arCInfo As New CultureInfo("ar-SA")
Dim usCInfo As New CultureInfo("en-US")

Dim InputType As String = If(price_2.Text.Contains("$"), "US", "AR")

Select Case InputType
    Case "US"
        If Decimal.TryParse(price_2.Text, numberStyle, usCInfo, CurrencyValue) Then
            price_2.Text = CurrencyValue.ToString("C", arCInfo)
        End If
    Case "AR"
        If Decimal.TryParse(price_2.Text, numberStyle, arCInfo, CurrencyValue) Then
            price_2.Text = CurrencyValue.ToString("C", usCInfo)
        End If
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with globalization but this worked for me. Just grab the number before formatting then you can apply the culture to the number itself.

```
Private dbl As Double
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dbl =CDbl(price_2.Text)
        Dim current_culture As New CultureInfo("ar-SA")
        price_2.Text = dbl.ToString("C", current_culture)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim current_culture As New CultureInfo("en-US")
        price_2.Text = dbl.ToString("C", current_culture)
End Sub
```